# python middleware to capture errors?

Tags: python, email, error-handling, middleware

is there a python middleware that captures errors from web app and emails it?
which is the easiest one to use.

i am deploying app using nginx proxying to multiple app servers of gunicorn+web.py framework.
right now any error is printed out in each app server, which is not very easy to manage.

what is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Python middleware? WSGI middleware? Django middleware?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Paste](http://pythonpaste.org/developer-features.html#debugging-filters). Code to email an exception would look something like:

```
from paste.exceptions.errormiddleware import ErrorMiddleware
app = ErrorMiddleware(app,
                      global_conf, debug=False,
                      error_email='foo@example.com',
                      smtp_server='localhost')
```